# Default expanded variables in VSCode Java debugger

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm using VSCode for Java development, and at some point in time, the debugging variables do not show the toString() results by default.  I have to click on the eyeball icon that has "Click to expand" tooltip.  In the example below, the Boolean before and after expanding.  Stepping through the code cases the view to reset to non-expanded.  How do I get the value to show by default?

[image: Variables view]

[image: Variables view after expanding]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can enable this setting `debug.autoExpandLazyVariables`