# auto expand variables in Visual Studio Code when debug

Tags: visual-studio-code, debugging, vscode-debugger

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWXJ9.png)
how to auto expand this "next"？

I already enable this setting debug.autoExpandLazyVariables，BUT NO USE
from [Default expanded variables in VSCode Java debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73428767/default-expanded-variables-in-vscode-java-debugger)

Comment: Your request is different from the shared question. That one is to turn off the lazy-resolve behavior in the variable view, so the debugger will always fetch the value of the variables as soon as possible. But AFAIK, VS Code does not have `expand all` support, that means you need to expand by your own.